# ASP.net MVC com WIF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autenticação, federation-authentication

Ao pesquisar na web, vi que não é possível registar assembly's na razor view engine no asp.net mvc como era feita na webforms.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wif" Namespace="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls" Assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```

como é possível fazer isso, renderizar um componente usando aspnet MVC?

Comment: É um `WebControl`?

Comment: Oi Cigano, no webforms seria um webcontrol, mas isso não existe no aspnet mvc.

Answer (score 2):

A maneira de registrar isso no Razor é bem parecida. Ficaria assim:

```
@{
    Register TagPrefix="wif" Namespace="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls" Assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
}
```

Há também um detalhe de registrar isso no seu `web.config` dentro do diretório `Views`:

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel" namespace="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls" tagPrefix="wif" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: cara.. isso não funcionou...